# How to downgrade phpMyAdmin version in MAMP PRO

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm currently using PHP 5.3.29 for my application and I can't currently upgrade it. I'm working on getting access to phpMyAdmin. I'm running MAMP PRO 4.2.1 which has phpMyAdmin version 4.7.3 which only allows PHP versions 5.5+ to access. I was thinking similar logic to http://blog-en.mamp.info/2013/08/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-mamp-mamp.html would apply for how to downgrade the version. I downloaded phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.20 and added the current config.inc.php file to the new phpMyAdmin folder I just downloaded. I then replaced the file in Applications/MAMP/bin as well as /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/. When I tried running localhost/phpmyadmin I wasn't able to connect. When I went to localhost/mamp I noticed under tools it still said I needed PHP 5.5+ to access phpMyAdmin. I then switched to CGI mode in MAMP Pro and changed localhost to 5.5.38 and when I went to localhost/phpmyadmin it was now working, but it still said I was using phpMyAdmin v4.7.3. So my question is how do I actually change the phpMyAdmin version used with MAMP Pro? I was under the impression that downloading old version and replacing in those two places mentioned should have taken care of it. I also made sure to restart server anytime I made a change to MAMP files so that's not the problem

Comment: **Danger** PHP 5.3 hasn't had a security update in almost four and a half years. You say you can't upgrade it, but you *really* need to. You should focus on fixing the problems blocking you from upgrading.

Comment: @Quentin If it was an option for me I would. It's out of my control at this moment but I keep bringing it up as much as possible. I was able to accomplish what I needed phpMyAdmin for but I still would like to figure out why making this change didn't work. I am only looking for answers to the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing everything necessary according to MAMP support in terms of changes, but they believe there was something in the code preventing me from viewing phpMyAdmin in a lower version. I ended up just using Sequel Pro to do what I needed and that was quite simple.